# Unity - POST error. How i can to repair it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, post

The post script, gives me an error.
There is my c# code

```
public IEnumerator POST()
  {
    Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
    headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");
    headers.Add("x-anketolog-apikey", "***");

    var Data = new WWWForm();
    Data.AddField("survey_id", "***");
    var Query = new WWW("https://apiv2.anketolog.ru/survey/answer/list", Data.data, headers);
    yield return Query;
    if (Query.error != null)
    {
      Debug.Log("Server does not respond : " + Query.error);
    }
    else
    {
      if (Query.text == "response")
      {
        Debug.Log("Server responded correctly");
      }
      else
      {
        Debug.Log("Server responded : " + Query.text);
      }
    }
    Query.Dispose();
  }
```

They give me an error: 422 unproccesable entity

I tryed to rewrite this code, and change field, where we have survey id. But nothing...

Comment: Why are you using Www to post. Thats been depreciated for a few years now

Comment: WWW been replace with UnityWebRequest : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html?force_isolation=true